# mPDF - file edges

Tags: php, mpdf

The text I have to write in PDF file with mPDF php library is supposed to start just below the edge/border of PDF file, in word it would mean the tabulators would be set close to 0 cm. I have only one A4 page of text.

What things I'm supposed to set to achive that? Can you help me with this?

```
$mpdf->autoPageBreak = false;
$mpdf->simpleTables = false;
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = false;
$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = false;
$mpdf->autoMarginPadding = 0;
$mpdf->bleedMargin = 0;
$mpdf->cropMarkMargin = false;
$mpdf->cropMarkLength = false;
```

Comment: what did you tried? where is your *problem* / what did not *function*? show us your code

Comment: Ok, I tried quite a lot:

$mpdf->autoPageBreak = false;
$mpdf->simpleTables = false;
$mpdf->setAutoBottomMargin = false;
$mpdf->setAutoTopMargin = false;
$mpdf->autoMarginPadding = 0;
$mpdf->bleedMargin = 0;
$mpdf->cropMarkMargin = false;
$mpdf->cropMarkLength = false;

I also tried setting those values to 0 too, but it didn't work. sorry for bad formatting here, haven't yet posted many things here.

Comment: @mihibo5 add code in your question, not in comments, it's unreadable here...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I did that.